# jquery click does not work after hover event works perfectly

Tags: jquery

I am still new on jquery and this is the problem that I am currently facing.
What I'm trying to do is to put hover and click event on the menu of a webpage,
hover event works perfectly but click event is not working.
Where should I fix? also, is it possible to combine the hover and click event to make the code shorter? Thank you in advance for the help.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".navi li a:first").addClass("active");

  $(".navi li a").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
  });

  $(".navi li a").click(function() {
    $(".navi li a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

}); //end
```

```css
.navi>li a.active {
  color: #0a2a43;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="navi">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--navi-->
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you need to use jquery for the hover? Can that not be achieved using the `:hover` psuedo in CSS?

Comment: Your click event is working. But usually when you click on an item you trigger `hoverIn` then `click` and finally `hoverOut` which is removing the `active` class of all your menu items.

Comment: The click event works. But after you click, you move the mouse away from the element, and that triggers the end of `hover`.

Comment: @freefaller Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to handle the "hover" in your jQuery, let the power of CSS do that

I've also improved your jQuery, so you're not getting the collection of elements time and time again... and changed the CSS so it's more obvious when the `.active` or `:hover` is used.

Additionally, you are effectively setting the `.active` on the first element both in the HTML *and* the jQuery... no need to do both, so for this example I've remove the HTML attribute.

```js
// Simpler "ready" format
$(function() {

  // Get all the elements once
  var $a = $(".navi li a");

  // Set the first one to "active"
  $a.first().addClass("active");

  // Click event
  $a.on("click", function(e) {
    // Stop navigation
    e.preventDefault();

    // Remove from all
    $a.removeClass("active");

    // Add to clicked
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
}); //end
```

```css
.navi>li a.active,
.navi>li a:hover{
  color: red;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul class="navi">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--navi-->
</nav>
```